# How can I switch time_now in a time interval? Or a better approach for this program?

Tags: android, time, switch-statement

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.get Instance();
            String time_now = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"          
                    + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    switch (time_now) {
              case 10:00 - 10:59
                 t x t.set Text("hi");             
                 break;
              case 11:00 - 11:59 
                 t x t.set Text("by");
                  break; 

    }
```

Comment: There is nothing you have done with `minutes`. it works in same way when you take `hour` alone for this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are covering the whole hour, from 00 to 59 minutes, there is no need to consider the minutes at all. Just switch on the hour itself. Your code should look like:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int time_now = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
switch (time_now) {
          case 10:
             t x t.set Text("hi");             
             break;
          case 11:
             t x t.set Text("by");
              break; 

}
```

Comment: Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted.

Comment: code edited above. just change the datatype of time_now to int

Answer (score 0):

try this code......

```
if(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)==10){
      if(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)>=0 && c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)<59){
           //do your work here ...
       }

 }
```

Comment: thanks, but error "MINUTE_OF_DAY cannot be resolved or is not a field"